# Can't print structure variable

Tags: c, struct, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int age;
} employee;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct employee em1 = {"Jack", 19};
    printf("%s", em1.name);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work because, as the compiler says, the variable has incomplete type of 'struct employee'. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Remove struct from

```
 struct employee em1 = {"Jack", 19};
```

You used

```
typedef struct
{
char name[20];
int age;
}
```

with the purpose of not requiring to type struct anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you made the struct a `typedef`, but are still qualifying it with `struct`.

This will work:

```
 employee em1 = {"Jack", 19};
```

Or remove the `typedef`.

Comment: Without the typedef it'd define a struct. It's just lacking a tag - `typedef struct employee {...} employee;`

Answer (score 0):

To use `struct employee em1 = ...` you need to declare the struct with a tag.

```
struct employee /* this is the struct tag */
{
char name[20];
int age;
} em1, em2; /* declare instances */
struct employee em3;
```

`typedef` creates a type alias which you use without the `struct` keyword.

```
typedef struct employee employee;
employee em4;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already typedef your structure, you are not required to add struct keyword again.

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[20];
    int age;
} employee;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    employee em1 = {"Jack", 19};
    printf("%s", em1.name);
    return 0;
}
```